# Passing context to domain in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo-9

In model

```
batch_id = fields.Many2one('ae.batch', 'Batch')
subject_ids = fields.Many2many('ae.subject', string="Subjects")
topic_ids = fields.Many2many('ae.topic', string="Topics")
subtopic_ids = fields.Many2many('ae.subtopic', string="Subtopics")
```

The goal is to pass context in order to filter(domain), picking a Batch filters Subjects, choose Subjects, could be one or more, to filter Topics, and filter Subtopics.

Batch (Many2one) to Subjects (Many2many)
Subjects (Many2many) to Topics (Many2many)
Topics (Many2many) to Subjects(Many2many)

Check view:

```
<group col="4" name="plan_detail" String='Choose t'>
<field name="batch_id" 
    context="{'batch_id':batch_id}"/>

<field name="subject_ids" 
    domain="[('batch_id', '=', batch_id)]" 
    context="{'subject_ids': subject_ids}"/>

<field name="topic_ids" 
    domain="[('subject_id', 'in', 'subject_ids')]"
    context="{'topic_ids': topic_ids}" />

<field name="subtopic_ids" widget="many2many_checkboxes" 
    domain="[('topic_id', 'in', topic_ids)]" />
```

What is working, picking the Batch filters correctly all Subjects.
Stucked between Subjects and Topics, I think is a context or domain problem, I've tested changing the domain manually like so:

```
<field name="topic_ids" 
    domain="[('subject_id', 'in', '[1, 2]')]"
    context="{'topic_ids': topic_ids}" />
```

And successfully gets Topic list. I guess I am wrong passing context or getting domain. Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, in the domain, the field that you mentioned subject_ids are in between quotes. Since its representing a field remove the quotes and do.

Try this

```
<field name="topic_ids" domain="[('subject_id', 'in', subject_ids)]"
    context="{'topic_ids': topic_ids}" />
```